# Using DOM for first time to change color of unanswered questions in form onSubmit

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

Here is my form:

```
<form id="Test" action="index.php?course=4" method="post" name="Test" onSubmit="IsFormComplete(12)">
```

Inside the form is a table dynamically generated with id=Qx class=Qx where x is 1 through 12:

```
 <tr id="Q2" class="Q2">  
            <td width="5%">2) </td>  
            <td colspan="2">According to the Institute of Medicine study the number of deaths from medical errors per year is between</td>
```

Here is my javascript function:

```
function IsFormComplete(iQuestions) {  
var questionNum = iQuestions;  
    itemOkay=true;  
    for (var i=1;i<questionNum;i++) {  
        for (var j=0;j<4;j++) {  
            var thisItem = eval("document.Test.Q" + i + "[" + j + "].checked");  
            if (!thisItem)  {  
                itemOkay = false;  
                document.getElementById(eval("Q" + i)).style.color = "red";  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    alert("item okay = " + itemOkay);  
    if (itemOkay) {  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        return false;  
    }
```

}

Not working PLEASE help. New to DOM and have tried various tags:

```
document.getElementById(eval("Q" + i)).style.color = "red";  
document.Test.getElementById(eval("Q" + i)).style.color = "red";  
document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";  //To try literal instead of variable
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the eval. getElementById uses a string. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("Q"+i).style.color = "red";
```

Comment: It is the simple things that screw with your caffeinated mind at the wee hours of the morning.